# Run JS function only on screen (not print)?

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a DIV with long text and truncate it with a function. That is all good, until someone will print the page. The truncated text won't be readable.

Is there some way I can prevent it?

I have looked for an equivalent for CSS's media print, but all I can find works with screen width. I don't know what is better: to truncate only on for media screen or to remove the truncation on 'print'.

```
// Truncate the job description
$(function() {
    if ( $('#jetsSearch').length ) {
        $('.job-description').readmore({
            speed: 100,
            collapsedHeight: 50,
            moreLink: '<a href="#">Read more</a>',
            lessLink: '<a href="#">Less</a>',
        });
    }
});
```

I tried this one, but it doesn't work (still truncated)

```
if ( $('#jetsSearch').length && window.matchMedia("screen").matches) {
```

Comment: why don't you do the truncation in CSS (using text-overflow: ellipsis)?

Comment: I think the OP was looking for this to be done via 3rd party library as he appears to be using `ReadMore.js`.  OP, i'd maybe tag your question with `jquery` and `readmore.js` to see if more peeps can come in to help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the **readmore.js** jquery plugin.

This is how I've handled the exact same issue. Readmore.js uses javascript to apply an inline style of height (among other things) to your container.  The only way to override those inline styles in your CSS it to use the `!important` rule in your declaration.

So by adding `height: auto;` to elements with the data attribute of `data-readmore` with the important rule, you can override this for print styles (I use a print media query in my CSS for this).  I also hide the "read more" link because it's irrelevant to printed pages.

```
@media print {
    [data-readmore] {
        height: auto !important;
    }
    [data-readmore-toggle] {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```